# Infinitivo pessoal após verbo conjugado

Tags: verbos, conjugações, infinitivo-pessoal

Dado a frase:

> Poderiam, por gentileza, responder**em**...

Sei caber o infinitivo impessoal *responder*, mas caberia também a forma *responderem*? Quais regras gramaticais estabelecem esse uso?

Comment: @tchrist Eliminaste o tag _gramática_ e juntaste _conjugação pronominal_. Eu penso duas vezes antes de desfazer o trabalho dum moderador e tenho uma compreensão mais intuitiva que formal da gramática, mas decididamente não existem conjugações pronominais nesta pergunta, portanto já tirei o tag. E parece-me que se  _poderia_ deve vir seguido do infinitivo ou do infinitivo pessoal é uma questão de gramática. Porque razão tiraste o tag?

Comment: @Jacinto Oh do please feel free to undo stuff that I screw up! :) Good question: you're right about this being an inflected verb  not an inflected pronoun; thanks for fixing that. (I was going too fast.) The issue with the [tag:gramática] tag is that [it does not tell you anything by itself](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and couldn’t stand alone. I have been trying to replace it with more particular tags that better describe **which** grammatical matter applies in each question, because I think that is of much more usefulness. I’ll make a meta post about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Poderiam, por gentileza, responder** é a única forma correta, com o infinitivo impessoal *responder;* o infinitivo pessoal *responderem* estaria errado. Podemos esclarecer a dúvida vendo como fica a frase com *poder* no presente do indicativo, forma a que estamos mais habituados, e também nas outras pessoas: *responder* fica bem no infinitivo impessoal, mas não no infinitivo pessoal.

> **Tu podes responder**, nunca *tu podes responderes*
>
> **Nós podemos responder**, nunca *nós podemos respondermos*
>
> **Vós podeis responder**, nunca *vós podeis responderdes*
>
> **Eles podem responder**, nunca *eles podem responderem*

Na primeira e terceira pessoas do singular, o infinitivo pessoal é igual ao infinitivo simples.

Na frase **poderiam, por gentileza, responder?** usa-se uma construção composta pelo [verbo auxiliar](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/verbos-auxiliares-portugues/) **poder** e o infinitivo **responder**. O infinitivo é uma [forma nominal](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/formas-nominais-do-verbo/). Outras construções compostas usam um verbo auxiliar e, como forma nominal, o gerúndio ou o particípio passado. Nas construções compostas, o verbo auxiliar é o único que concorda com o sujeito. A **forma nominal** é sempre invariável:

> Nós podemos/eles deverão/tu precisas (de)/vocês quiseram/nós tínhamos de/nós desejaríamos **responder**
>
> Nós não estamos/eles andaram **espalhando** boatos (especialmente ptBR)
>
> Nós não estamos/eles andaram **a espalhar** boatos (ptPT)
>
> Nós temos/eles haviam **visto** o Fábio